# changing angular config based on azure deployment slot

Tags: angular, azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Angular application that references an API for its data. I'm using Visual Studio Team Services (TFS online) for the Build and Release pipeline and Azure App Service for hosting.

Depending on which environment the application is in the pipeline - Dev -> Stage -> Prod - the application should utilize a different API for its data. For example, if it's is in the Dev environment it should reference http://someapi-dev.azurewebsites.net and if it's in Stage, it should reference http://someapi-stage.azurewebsites.net.

The Dev environment is its own Azure App Service. The Stage and Prod environments are deployment slots on the same Azure App Service. When I release from Stage to Prod, it is a simple slot swap operation.

The problem is that I can't carry the same Angular configuration through all the environments. The config must change to reflect the proper API to use.

How do I make this dynamic? I can use a Command Line step to overwrite the config file when I deploy to Dev (e.g. "move /Y config.dev.json config.json"). However, how do I do a similar operation when swapping slots from Stage to Prod?

Here's how I'm loading the appropriate API url at runtime in app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('assets/environments/config.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .toPromise()
    .then((config) => {
      this.apiSvc.baseUrl = config.urlToApi;
      this.isConfigReady = true;
});
```

Comment: So to be clear, your API endpoint is specified in a JSON config file? Also, are you using ASP.NET MVC + Angular?

Comment: @RobReagan - yes, the API endpoint is specified in a JSON config file. I edited the question to reflect that. Yes, this project is using ASP.NET MVC + Angular.

Comment: @aobrientrin Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had to deal with this myself.

Try moving your config.json from a static file to an MVC View. You can set up a route to a .js file in your RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
       name: "configRoute", 
       url: "settings/config.js", 
       defaults: new { controller = "Settings", action="Index" }
   );
```

Once you do this, you can read data from the  section of your web.config file and insert it into your config.json. You'll then be able to set your endpoint as an app setting.

For example, in your Views\Settings\index.cshtml that will serve your config.json file:

```
  @using System.Configuration

    {
        "endpoint": @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configEndpoint"]
    }
```

After you've done this, it simplifies what you're trying to do. You can now go to the Application Settings section in your Azure Web App and set the value you need accordingly. The slot swap is simple too if you just mark the app setting as a Slot Setting.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the src path of your angular app you must have a folder which name is environments. Within that you have all environments. So you just have to import `import { environment } from './environments/environment';` . The import path depends on your app configuration. So you can then get the current env and according to that check which API to call.
Here is the environment content

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

I hope base on this you can get the current environment

Comment: that is a good question, since your answer more directly answered the OPs question. So here is an upvote on me.  The other answer is actually a valid but different problem.

Comment: cause we dont want to rebuild the ng app when we swap environments (stg => prod)